# FirebaseFirestore add List

Tags: flutter, firebase, list, google-cloud-firestore

On a Add Device Page i insert the device name and the class, and as soon as i click on the add button it should be added to the firestore database and i'll be able to see it on the home page.

I tried to add a list onto FirebaseFirestore, but the error "The input method toggled cursor monitoring on" occurred.

This is the function to add the Device to Firebase

```
  void addDevice() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          color: Colors.purple,
        ),
      ),
    );
    if (_deviceNameController.text.isEmpty ||
        _deviceClassController.text.isEmpty) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      showErrorMessage("Please fill out all fields".tr);
    } else if (_deviceNameController.text.length > 20) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      showErrorMessage("Device Name can be a maximum of 20 characters long".tr);
    } else if (_deviceNameController.text.length <= 1) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      showErrorMessage("Device Name must be at least 2 characters long".tr);
    } else if (_deviceClassController.text != "Light".tr &&
        _deviceClassController.text != "Power Socket".tr &&
        _deviceClassController.text != "Screen".tr &&
        _deviceClassController.text != "Camera".tr &&
        _deviceClassController.text != "Gate".tr) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      showErrorMessage("Class not found".tr);
    } else {
      if (_deviceClassController.text == "Light".tr) {
        String path = "assets/icons/lamp.png";
        IconData iconOn = CupertinoIcons.sun_max;
        IconData iconOff = CupertinoIcons.moon;
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserDevices').add({
          'deviceName': _deviceNameController.text,
          'cassPath': path,
          'textOn': "On",
          'textOff': "Off",
          'iconOn': iconOn,
          'iconOff': iconOff,
        });
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the Home Page Gridview

```
Expanded(
                  child: RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: () async {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                    displacement: 2,
                    child: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('UserDevices')
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return GridView.builder(
                            itemCount: DeviceList.devices.length,
                            gridDelegate:
                                const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    crossAxisCount: 2),
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final device = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                              return DeviceTile(
                                deivceName: device['deviceName'],
                                classPath: device['cassPath'],
                                textOn: device['textOn'],
                                textOff: device['textOff'],
                                iconOn: device['iconOn'],
                                iconOff: device['iconOff'],
                                onLongPress: () => deleteDevice(index),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Text("Error"),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you manually check if the write is successful in Firestore?

I think you are missing 'await' when committing the write to Firestore. And you pop to the previous screens and tried to load the snapshots from Firestore when the write is not completed yet.

Try changing to this

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserDevices').add({
      'deviceName': _deviceNameController.text,
      'cassPath': path,
      'textOn': "On",
      'textOff': "Off",
      'iconOn': iconOn,
      'iconOff': iconOff,
    });
```